# Пересечение двух списков с повторениями на Python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Как можно реализовать алгоритм нахождения пересечения списков, состоящих из целых чисел? Через множества пробовал, но тогда не выводит повторяющиеся элементы. Знаю, что можно вложенными циклами пройтись по спискам и вывести одинаковые элементы, но не получается реализовать. Необходимо, чтобы сложность алгоритма была **О(len(list1)+len(list2))**. Если кто поможет, буду благодарен. 
**Пример:**

```
list1 = [1,3,7,9,10]
list2 = [2,3,4,7,8,11]
```

Ответ: `[3, 7]`

Пример с повторами:

```
list1 = [1,3,3,4,6]
list2 = [3,3,3,6,8,9]
```

тогда вывести должно `[3,3,6]`.

Comment: Приведите пример с повторяющимися элементами и что ожидаемый вывод

Comment: У вас же все уже отсортировано в обоих списках, в этом случае лучше использовать ассоциативный массив индекс:значение, тогда можно сделать прогон по наиболее длинному списку и проверить на существование в другом по индексу; индекс и там и там будет равен значению, т.е индекс для значения 3 будет равен 3.

Comment: @danielprotopopov я не очень понял про то какой ассоциативный массив надо создать, а также не уверен в том, что будет выполняться указанная сложность алгоритма.

Comment: @m9_psy например list1 = [1,3,3,4,6] list2 = [3,3,3,6,8,9] тогда вывести должно [3,3,6]

Comment: Я имел в виду что вы берёте список с самым большим значением и используете его как основной. Проходите по нему и проверяете если list2[list1[index]] существует. Если да, то это значение берётся как существующее в обеих списках.

Comment: @danielprotopopov попробую, конечно, спасибо за идею

Comment: Хотя в вашем комментарии это не получится. Даже не знаю, НО уже есть готовый метод intersection, для этого придётся конвертировать список в set. Опять же не могу сказать какая там будет сложность перебора. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/python-intersection-of-two-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если списки отсортированы, то можно так:

```
def find_intersection(l1, l2):
    out = []
    i1 = 0
    i2 = 0
    while (i1 < len(l1)) and (i2 < len(l2)):
        if l1[i1] > l2[i2]:
            i2 += 1
        elif l1[i1] < l2[i2]:
            i1 += 1
        else: #l1[i1] == l2[i2]
            out.append(l1[i1])
            i1 += 1
            i2 += 1
    return out
```

Comment: А если не отсортированы, то я сомневаюсь в достижимости O(N)

Comment: @andy.37 через хеш-таблицы должно получится, только надо как то сделать так. чтобы повторяющиеся элементы отображались

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Ситуацию с неотсортированными списками не рассматриваю, так что алгоритм корректный.

Answer (score 8):

Чтобы найти пересечение списков с учётом повторений, можно использовать вместо простого `set` (уникальные элементы) класс с [multiset семантикой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) (элементы могут более одного раза встречаться) такой как [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

common_items = list((Counter(list1) & Counter(list2)).elements())
# -> [3, 3, 6]
```

Comment: по-моему, это самое профессиональное решение (из приведенных)

Answer (score 2):

Для неотсортированных списков, исходя из предположения, что операция
`d.get(key, None)` для произвольного словаря `d` имеет сложность O(1):

```
def count(l):
    d = {}
    for i in l:
        v = d.get(i, 0)
        d[i] = v + 1
    return d

l1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3]    # count(l1) = {1:2, 2:1, 3:2, 4:1}
l2 = [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 2] # count(l2) = {1:3, 2:1, 3:2, 5:1}

r = []
d = count(l2)
for i, v in count(l1).items():
    w = d.get(i, 0)
    for j in range(min(v, w)):
        r.append(i)

print r # r = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Если писать короче:

```
def count(l):
   d = {} # d = collections.defaultdict(int)
   for i in l:
      d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1 # d[i] += 1
   return d

r = []
d = count(l2)
for i, v in count(l1).items():
   r += [i] * min(v, d.get(i, 0))
```

Генератор списков сюда (имхо) не влезает никак.

Comment: Такие ужасы ни к чему (есть `dict.setdefault`, ещё лучше есть `collections.defaultdict` и ещё лучше [`collections.Counter`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618130/23044))

Comment: @jfs вообще забавно, что в целом неплохо зная питон, я прошел совсем мимо модуля `collections`. Зато в пяти строчках написано, как устроен `collection.Counter`))

Comment: ++ за вашу реализацию `Counter` ;-) Интересно было бы сравнить производительность для больших списков - я думаю `Counter` будет намного быстрее

Comment: @MaxU даже без  Counter, попробуйте  count() написать используя defaultdict и сравните код. Другие имена переменных могли бы улучшить читаемость кода. Генератор списка здесь также можно было бы использовать.

Comment: @jfs, согласен, здесь можно многое еще улучшить...

Comment: @jfs `setdefaults` тут не поможет ничем. `collection.defaultdics` - да, будет очень удобно, в стиле Perl. Но см. мой комментарий выше. Что касается сравнения эффективности `count` и `Counter`, то единственная оптимизация - писать на C, так-то там нечего оптимизировать. Ну да, получение конечного списка можно элегантнее написать, но придумывать имена для 5-строчной функции - это лишнее.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(i for i in list1 if i in list2)
```

Прокрутка всего одного массива

Comment: Печатает `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f3cfa25fd00>`

Comment: Так не достигается указанная сложность алгоритма

Comment: N*M сложность...

Comment: И с повторяющимися элементами это будет некорректно работать - выведет все повторения из первого списка, если во втором есть хотя бы один такой элемент.

Answer (score 0):

```
sp1 = [1,2,3,4,5,3]
sp2 = [3,4,5,6,7,3]

sp3 = []
for i in sp1:
    if i in sp2:
        sp3.append(i)

print(sp3)# [3, 4, 5, 3]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: это неверный ответ даёт: выведет все элементы из sp1 которые хотя бы раз в sp2 встречаются. Также как и здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618075/23044