# тип Counter() - словарь или множество?

Tags: python, коллекции

В описании типа [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) сказано что он - наследник dict. И не сказано, что он также и множество. Приведенный ниже код работает и выдает результат:     `Counter({'q': 1, 'w': 1})`

```
from collections import Counter
c1 = Counter({'q':1, "w":2})
c2 = Counter({'q':1, "w":1})
c = c1 & c2
print(c)
```

Вопрос - почему не описано, что он - множество? Или он "не вполне" множество?

Comment: Цитата по вашей ссылке: Several mathematical operations are provided for combining Counter objects to produce multisets (counters that have counts greater than zero). Addition and subtraction combine counters by adding or subtracting the counts of corresponding elements. Intersection and union return the minimum and maximum of corresponding counts. Each operation can accept inputs with signed counts, but the output will exclude results with counts of zero or less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это объект типа `Counter` (наследник `dict`) [для которого перегружен оператор `&` (`__and__(...)`)](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/collections.py#L617-L632):

```
def __and__(self, other):
    ''' Intersection is the minimum of corresponding counts.
    >>> Counter('abbb') & Counter('bcc')
    Counter({'b': 1})
    '''
    if not isinstance(other, Counter):
        return NotImplemented
    result = Counter()
    for elem, count in self.items():
        other_count = other[elem]
        newcount = count if count < other_count else other_count
        if newcount > 0:
            result[elem] = newcount
    return result
```

Примеры:

```
In [54]: issubclass(Counter, dict)
Out[54]: True

In [55]: issubclass(Counter, set)
Out[55]: False

In [39]: type(c)
Out[39]: collections.Counter

In [40]: c.items()
Out[40]: dict_items([('q', 1), ('w', 1)])

In [41]: type(c.items())
Out[41]: dict_items

In [42]: c.keys()
Out[42]: dict_keys(['q', 'w'])
```

Comment: спрошу по другому. Является ли действительно Counter наследником типа dict и set одновременно. В смысле ООП. Сорри, забыл как это можно посмотреть =D

Comment: @MaxU глупый вопрос. Если это настоящий код, то почему не обрабатывается ошибка ключа для оператора `other_count = other[elem]` ?

Comment: @splash58, об этом должен позаботиться перегруженный оператор __getitem__ для соответствующего класса (other)

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
c1 = Counter({'q':1, "w":2})

print type(c1) #<class 'collections.Counter'>
d1={'q':1, "w":2}
print type(d1)            # Выведем тип переменной d1 <type 'dict'>
isinstance(d1, dict)      # является ли переменная d1 переменной класса dict? True
issubclass(Counter, dict) # наследуется ли Counter от dict? True
issubclass(Counter, set)  # наследуется ли Counter от set ? False
```

Answer (score 2):

Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> The Counter class is similar to bags or [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) in other languages.

`Counter` может быть использован как [мультимножество](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE). К примеру: буквы слова образуют мультимножество (буквы могут повторяться). В Питоне, это понятие полезно в задачах, с неупорядоченными списками:

- [Пересечение двух списков с повторениями на Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618130/23044)
- [Сравнение двух списков на нахождение элементов которые соответствуют правилам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/590198/23044)

`Counter` реализован как подкласс словаря (dict), где ключ это элемент, а значение это количество его повторений. Основное назначение `Counter` это подсчёт хэшируемых объектов. К примеру: частота слов в тексте.

Обычный словарь не определяет `+`, `-`, `&`, `|` операции. [Почему нельзя просто взять и сложить два словаря?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431760/23044) Для `Counter`  с положительными счётчиками эти операции позволяют комбинировать мультимножества c очевидной семантикой:

- `+`: счётчики складываются
- `-`: вычитаются (неположительные счётчики удаляются — соответствуют отсутствующим элементам)
- `&`: пересечение содержит элементы из обоих множеств (минимум значений счётчиков)
- `|`: слияние — максимум.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> help(Counter)
sh: more: not found
Help on class Counter in module collections:

class Counter(builtins.dict)
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Counter
 |      builtins.dict
 |      builtins.object
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
....
```

`help` пишет что не наследуется `Counter` от `set`.