# Объединение двух списков без потери одинаковых значений

Tags: python-3.x

Нужно сделать так называемое логическое объединение двух списков (&):

a=[1,2,3,3,4] 
b=[2,3,3,5]

a & b=[2,3,3]

Знаю, что есть объединение для множеств, но там исключаются повторные значения.

Comment: Для a=[1,2,3,4,5,6] и b=[1,2,3,2,1,4,5,6,5,4] какой ожидается результат?

Comment: andreymal, [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: Нужно, чтобы программа возвратила те значения, которые содержатся в обоих списках. Причём, если в одном списке содержится, например, 2 пятёрки, а другом - 3 пятёрки, то объединение должно быть - 2 пятёрки

Comment: Что-то я пока не могу алгоритма понять. Для a=[3,4,3,5,3,7,8,9] и b=[8,7,5,3] какой ожидается результат?

Comment: andreymal, [3,5,7,8]

Comment: Чтоб вам было проще понять, это требуется для нахождения НОД двух чисел: после того, как мы разложили оба числа на множители, нам нужно найти общие множители

Comment: @ГолованенкоВиктор про НОД лучше отдельно спросить. Можно с `math.gcd()` начать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list((Counter([1,2,3,3,4]) & Counter([2,3,3,5])).elements())
[2, 3, 3]
```

[тип Counter() - словарь или множество?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/762174/23044)

Comment: Вопрос не по теме :) По ссылке код приведен. А почему там для строки `other_count = other[elem]` нет обработки отсутствия ключа?

Comment: @splash58: лучше задайте этот вопрос там, где вы этот код увидели (я не вижу в какой ссылке вы это нашли). Результат ожидаемый: сколько раз встречается отсутствующее значение -- `0`.

Comment: Ответ MaxU чуть выше. там мне не очевидно, что код `a={1:1}; a[2]` не вызовет ошибку. Сейчас спрошу :)

Comment: @splash58 `{1:1}` создаёт словарь, а не Counter. `a[2]` вызовет ошибку. Я  не вижу никакой связи с текущим ответом.

Answer (score 2):

Без дополнительных модулей

```
res = []
for x in set(a+b):
  t = min(a.count(x), b.count(x))
  if t > 0:
    res += [x]*t
print(res)
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/928666)

Comment: collections не дополнительный модуль, если что :)

Comment: @andreymal Я тут решил питону поучиться :) Пока до синтаксиса руки дошли :)

Comment: избегайте квадратичных алгоритмов, если ввод не ограничен